# Add AndroidTest build type for all flavors in whitelabel app

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane

I have a whitelabel Android app, that uses flavors to build the different variants. I have setup the application so that all variants are built with fastlane, and everything works correctly except when it comes to AndroidTest, and its usage to generate screenshots.

According to fastlane's [docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/screenshots/) (see section `Generating Screenshots with Screengrab`) I should be able to run the following gradle tasks and get a build ready for screenshots to be taken:

```rb
gradle(task: "clean")
  
gradle(
   task: 'assemble',
   flavor: options[:flavor],
   build_type: 'Debug'
)

gradle(
   task: 'assemble',
   flavor: options[:flavor],
   build_type: 'AndroidTest'
)
```

The first two actions work without issues, the problem is the third one where the gralde task generated looks like this: `assemble<flavour>AndroidTest`, where `<flavour>` is the name of the flavour I am trying to build. The problem is that there isn't a gradle task for each of the flavours, but a generic one called `assembleAndroidTest`.

How can I add a gradle task (possibly automatically), that follows the pattern above, for each of the flavors in my project?

***EDIT***

I may have found a solution, although I am not sure this is correct:

```rb
gradle(
  task: 'assemble',
  flavor: options[:flavor],
  build_type: 'DebugAndroidTest'
)
```

By setting the build type to be `DebugAndroidTest` it works, although I not sure whether I will run into issues down the road.

Could it be a workaround though?

Comment: I guess you could just skip `flavour` for your AndroidTest then because `assembleAndroidTest` should build the test variant for all flavours.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for my case. I have a few flavours that require additional data/are not going to build when using this gradle task. I need to be sure I can target a specific flavour when executing the gradle task.